# Why does my fancybox not open on $('.selector').click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-3

I have a page of styled links that I broke into sections using jQuery.

1. Using jQuery `.internal` causes the page to navigate to the specified target specified by the `href` attribute of the link inside the div the user clicked on.
2. `.external` does the same thing as `.internal` except it opens in a new tab.
3. `.video` should simply cause the div clicked to play the video specified by the link in a fancybox but it does not. Nor does it report an error in the console.

Here is my code for the fancybox:

**HTML**

```
<div id="fentanylVid" class="col-sm-3 dept video" data-department="fentanyl the real deal">
    <div class="box listed-left animated-content move_right animate clearfix">
        <div class="box-text">
            <h4><a data-fancybox="" href="https://youtu.be/Tt0dFCuwkfQ?rel=0">Fentanyl: The Real Deal (Video)</a></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.video').click(function(){
    $().fancybox({
        selector : '.video'
    });
});
```

I also have the two resources in the header of my page

Comment: Going by https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#api it looks like the API command to open a fancybox is `$.fancybox.open`

Comment: This is a step closer. It does cause the fancybox to open when the div is clicked, but it does not play the video specified by the link within the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either initialize the fancybox like this

```
$('.video').fancybox({
    selector : '.video'
});
```

or as @Taplar said

```
$('.video').click(function(){
    $.fancybox.open(this)
});
```

Comment: I got it to work using a version of @Taplar suggestion. may I edit your answer to show it?

Answer (score 1):

A bit explaining what your code does:

```
$('.video').click(function(){ // <- Here you are attaching your click event on selected items
    // So, when user clicks, this happens:
    $().fancybox({ // Here you are telling fancybox to attach click event ..
        selector : '.video'  // .. on this selector
    });
});
```

So, basically you have done too much work and all you have to do is to remove your own click event and it should work fine. Or you can use API to start fancybox programmatically, like in the other answer.